# Installing PlayOrm in PlayFramework 2.1?

Tags: playorm

Steps I took:

1. Started a new Play application.
2. Created a lib folder.
3. Copied to lib: playOrm/output/jardist/*.jar + playorm/output/libs/playorm.jar + playorm/src/resources/play2plugin/plugin2.1jar
4. Changed the conf and added play.plugins.conf as per: http://buffalosw.com/wiki/PlayFramework-2.x-support/
5. At this point, I started play and got a missing class exception for google gson. I added that to the lib as well.

Now, when I run the play app I get:

> Plugin [play.CorePlugin] cannot been instantiated.
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   play.CorePlugin.(play.Application)

What am I missing?

UPDATE: Corrected the filename in my original post from plugin.conf to play.plugins and adding the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: play.CorePlugin.<init>(play.Application)
   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
   java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
       play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Application.scala:137)
       play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Application.scala:130)
   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
   ...
```

Comment: I don't use the play2.1 but will ask Vikas to take a look as he wrote this piece.

Comment: and we will update the docs as well if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It seems that play1.x.jar is in your classpath. As CorePlugin exist in Play1.x only. Please remove that.

Comment: You are right. It was in the playorm/output/jardist folder which I copied wholesale in step 3. Removing play-1.2.5.jar fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Great. We have updated the documentation as well for future users.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you please provide the complete stack trace as it seems this is due to Play and not Playorm as such.
2. As your comments above says, you created plugin.conf..That is not required. Please see the document, we need /conf/play.plugins file with the following content

   5000:com.alvazan.play2.Play2Plugin

Comment: I mistyped. I meant play.plugins. I will correct my question and add the stack trace